# Getting Valid Inputs for Constrained Field

Tags: database, perl, informix

I have an Informix database that I really would have liked an 'enum' field for. Being that Informix (At least in the version I am constrained to) has no built-in enum type I used some Google-Foo to find out that I could constrain a VARCHAR field to only allow certain values like so:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (type IN ('type1',  'type2', 'type3'));
```

This seems to work well. Now I need to connect to the database from a Perl script that checks user input against those valid values. I can of course check them in code and make sure my code knows what the values are that the database requires, but I wondered if there is any way I could have my script query the constraint on the database therefore if I need to Add/Remove a valid input at a later time I could just alter the constraint and the processing code would adapt.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encapsulate you database access in a [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass) schema, you gain this kind of validation "as a bonus".
A simple way of generating the schema from a pre-existing database is by
[dbicdump](https://metacpan.org/module/dbicdump).

Comment: Thanks for that! Perl is not my specialty so I'm still getting used to CPAN.